# Why don't proxychains like programs work in Windows unlike linux?

Tags: linux, windows-10, networking, proxy, http-proxy

I wounder something deadly.

I use proxychains to direct traffic of any program to http proxy in linux. It doesn't make a difference wheter this traffic http or https.

On the other hand, for windows, I used Proxifier and ProxyCap. I exprienced that I can direct http traffic only to http proxy, https traffic https proxy as well.

But in linux, it doesnt matter wheter it is http or https traffic. Proxychains can handle those traffic with http proxy.

What is the reason of it ?

Browsers can use my dorm http proxy with http or https traffics in windows and linux. So I am expecting that there should be a software that equivalent proxychains(or redsocks) for Windows.

My second question is, why proxifier and ProxyCap handle https traffics with http proxy even browsers can ??

I owe you if you answer them...